# Algorithm: search for incremental sequences of integers from multiple ordered lists

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to find the most efficient way to find a sequence of integers from an array (or list) of sorted integer arrays (lists).
Suppose I have this array

```
{
{1, 3, 4, 9, 15},
{5, 10, 13},
{2, 6, 11, 17},
{7, 8, 12}
}
```

Then the solution should return the array of arrays of consecutive incremental numbers

```
{ {4, 5, 6, 7}, {9, 10, 11, 12} }
```

In the result, the 4 and 9 come from the first sub-array, the 5 and 10 come from the second and so on. The constraint is that all arrays in the final output must have a fixed length of the number of arrays in the input, i.e, all arrays in the input must provide 1 element in each array in the result.

We can assume that the input arrays are sorted, and that there are no duplications in the input arrays, e.g in the example, if 9 is in array 1, I can assume that 9 will not be in any other input array.

Is there any effective way to do it? I cannot come up with anything apart from brute-forcing the arrays. Using any data structure and algorithm is accepted.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not `{ {1, 5, 6, 7}, {9, 10, 11, 12} }`?

Comment: @Andreas I guess he is looking for only consecutive numbers.

Comment: The answer is essentially a four-way merge sort. But since the full output of the sort is not needed, the algorithm can skip ahead in the lists with an [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pick first value from first array, and save it as `prevValue`.
2. Build an array of positions (indexes) into each input array, initializing them to 0.
3. Iterate over input arrays:

   - Advance position for given input array until value is `>= prevValue`.
     If end of input array is reached, stop, you're done.
   - Update `prevValue` to value found.
4. Now the position array stores the positions of the next sequence of incrementing values. Save values to result.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until you're done.

---

As code, that would be something like this:

```
private static int[][] findIncrementalSequences(int[][] input) {
    int[] pos = new int[input.length];
    int prevValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    List<int[]> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (;;) {
        int[] result = new int[pos.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
            while (pos[i] < input[i].length && input[i][pos[i]] <= prevValue)
                pos[i]++;
            if (pos[i] == input[i].length)
                return results.toArray(new int[results.size()][]);
            prevValue = result[i] = input[i][pos[i]];
        }
        results.add(result);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
int[][] input = { {1, 3, 4, 9, 15},
                  {5, 10, 13},
                  {2, 6, 11, 17},
                  {7, 8, 12} };
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(findIncrementalSequences(input)));
```

*Output*

```
[[1, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

---

**UPDATE**

If each sub-result must be consecutive incrementing values, the code can be modified to restart at `input[0]` if the next number is not exactly 1 higher than previous value.

The following code was also slightly changed to remove duplicate array lookups.

```
private static int[][] findConsecutiveSequences(int[][] input) {
    int[] pos = new int[input.length];
    int nextValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE, value;
    List<int[]> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (;;) {
        int[] result = new int[pos.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
            for (;;) {
                if (pos[i] == input[i].length)
                    return results.toArray(new int[results.size()][]);
                if ((value = input[i][pos[i]]) >= nextValue)
                    break;
                pos[i]++;
            }
            if (i == 0 || value == nextValue) {
                result[i] = value;
                nextValue = value + 1;
            } else {
                i = -1; // Restart with input[0]
            }
        }
        results.add(result);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
[[4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: the first `prevValue` should be the smallest one but it doesn't guarantee that the first value from first inner array is the smallest

Comment: @You'reawesome So what? It is the smallest *usable* value from first array. Any smaller values from other array can never be used, so they are meaningless to the result. --- Example: If we drop the first input array, `prevValue` will initially be 5. The value `2` from the next array can never be part of the result, so why would we care that it exists?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the answer, but what I need in the output is arrays of _consecutive_ integers. Sorry for not making that clear in the question.